# How to have charts include added rows in google docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

The problem is, it it's modifying my range selection. In the chart I select ranges `Sheet2!A:A, Sheet2!B:B`, but after clicking ok, and going back into the chart, it modified my range selection to `Sheet2!A1:A161, Sheet2!B1:B161` which includes all of the rows currently in the document, but if I add another row, it is not added to the chart. Is there a way to have new rows automatically added to the chart?

Comment: Why did you add the google-document tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided you add a row adjacent to one already included in the chart and (I think!) is within the range selected when first inserting the chart.

Comment: Remark: if one uses "add (N) rows", they will all be included in the chart provided that the data is entered in these rows in the top-to-bottom order. Each row will be included upon being filled. But if one enters data in a wrong order (e.g., bottom to top), that breaks the association with the chart.